# ¿Cuál es el orden de ejecución usando esta estructura de promises?

Tags: javascript, promesas, ecmascript-2015

Dado este código:

```
let promise =new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    console.log("uno");
    resolve();
});
promise.then(function(){
    var cont=1;
    promise.then(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            cont++;
        };
        console.log(5);
    });
    promise.then(function(){
        console.log("dos");
        console.log("tres");
    });
});
promise.then(function(){
    console.log("cuatro");
})
```

El orden de ejecución que espero es:

1. "uno" (que se ejecute el for)
2. "cinco"
3. "dos" y "tres"
4. "cuatro"

**Nota:** hice la prueba de mi código y se ejecuta:

```
uno->cuatro->cinco->dos->tres
```

entiendo que antes que se mande a resolve(), se respeta el tiempo de ejecucion de las tareas antes de resolve
por ejemplo:

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('cinco');
        resolve('cinco');
      }, 5000);
    })
```

luego que pasa 5 segundos procede a ejecutar los then(y es lo que buscaba, aca se respeta el orden de ejecucion)

pero en .then si es que uno de ellos dura mas que los otros se ejecuta al final, ya entiendo eso por las explicaciones, pero no hay alguna forma que se respete un then luego que termine proceda por el otro then?

```
.then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'cinco'
setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("dos");
},2000);
      return 'dos';
    })
.then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'dos'
      console.log("tres");
      return 'tres';
    });
```

la devolucion es "tres"->"dos"

modificacion: ejemplo nuevo con modificaciones de settimeout en .then

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log('uno');
  resolve('uno');
});
promise.then(function (res) {
    // res es igual a 'uno'
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('cinco');
        resolve('cinco');
      }, 5000);
    })

    // Este then SI esta encadenado
    .then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'cinco'
      setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("dos");
  },2000);
      return 'dos';
    })
    // Este then NO esta encadenado al then anterior
    .then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'dos'
      console.log("tres");
      return 'tres';
    });
    // Acá le estamos indicando que todos los `then` encadenados
    // esperen a que se resuelva esta nueva promesa
    return p;
  })
  // Este then SI esta encadenado al then anterior
  .then(function (res) {
    // res es igual a 'dos', porque 'tres' no esta encadenado
    console.log('cuatro: ' + res);
  });
```

no respeta el orden de ejecucion en el

```
.then(function (res) {
          // res es igual a 'cinco'
          setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("dos");
      },2000);
          return 'dos';
        })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// Error:

> El error radica en la interpretación errónea en el flujo de ejecución.

Cada declaración `then` lo que hace es `poner en cola` la función pasada.

Este sería tu código, con unas pequeñas modificaciones, para que se entienda mejor el flujo de ejecución.

```js
let promise = new Promise(f1);
promise.then(f2);
promise.then(f3);

//

function f1(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("uno");
  resolve();
}

function f2() {
  var cont = 1;
  promise.then(f4);
  promise.then(f5);

  //

  function f4() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cont++;
    };
  }

  function f5() {
    console.log("dos");
    console.log("tres");
  }
}

function f3() {
  console.log("cuatro");
}
```

Como se puede ver, las funciones se ejecutaran en el orden que fueron `puestas en cola`, primero `f1, f2, f3` y al ejecutarse `f2`, las funciones `f4 y f5`, son `puestas en cola`, es decir, después de `f3`.

// Solución:

> el orden de ejecución que espero es: "uno"->"que se ejecute el for"->"cinco"->"dos"-"tres"->"cuatro".

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("uno");
  resolve();
});
promise.then(function() {
  var cont = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cont++;
  }
  console.log(5);
  console.log("dos");
  console.log("tres");
});
promise.then(function() {
  console.log("cuatro");
});
```

// Update (`sin eliminar una función`)

> como seria tu código sin eliminar una función ???

```js
let promise =new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  console.log("uno");
  resolve();
});
promise.then(function(){
  var cont=1;
  promise.then(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cont++;
    };
    console.log(5);
  });
  promise.then(function(){
    console.log("dos");
    console.log("tres");
  });
  promise.then(function(){
    console.log("cuatro");  
  });
});
```

// Update (`timeout`)

> quiero que siga el mismo orden, ya que el timeout puede significar un for o alguna tarea que tarde

Encadenando promesas ([`Chaining promises`](https://www.promisejs.org/)), es decir, que cada `then` reciba el valor devuelto por el anterior.

Haciendo uso de esta propiedad, se puede resolver así:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log('uno');
  resolve('uno');
});
promise.then(function (res) {
  // res es igual a 'uno'
  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('cinco');
      resolve('cinco');
    }, 2000);
  })
  // Este then SI esta encadenado
  .then(function (res) {
    // res es igual a 'cinco'
    console.log("dos");
    return 'dos';
  });
  // Este then NO esta encadenado al then anterior
  p.then(function (res) {
    // res es igual a 'dos'
    console.log("tres");
    return 'tres';
  });
  // Acá le estamos indicando que todos los `then` encadenados
  // esperen a que se resuelva esta nueva promesa
  return p;
})
// Este then SI esta encadenado al then anterior
.then(function (res) {
  // res es igual a 'dos', porque 'tres' no esta encadenado
  console.log('cuatro: ' + res);
});
```

**Importante**: No es lo mismo hacer `promise.then` que `.then()` ( es decir, hacer `chaining`).

// Update (`nueva pregunta`)

> no hay alguna forma que se respete un then luego que termine proceda por el otro then?

Si, usando `chaining`, como ya lo demostré en el **Update del `timeout`**

Para solucionar `dos` debes hacer lo mismo que en `cinco`, deberias crear una `promise` para esperar la respuesta del `timeout` (pseudo-evento asíncrono) y hacer el `return` de esta nueva promise.

Comment: Edite mi codigo. Puse el .log(5), como seria tu codigo sin eliminar una funcion ???

Comment: @marcosGallado modificando un poco tu codigo, cambia el orden de ejecucion `let promise =new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    console.log("uno");
    resolve();
});
promise.then(function(){
    var cont=1;
    promise.then(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(5);
        },1)
        
    });
    promise.then(function(){
        console.log("dos");
        console.log("tres");
    });
    promise.then(function(){
        console.log("cuatro");  
    });
});`

Comment: quiero que siga el mismo orden, ya que el timeout puede significar un for o alguna tarea que tarde

Comment: estas seguro que cuando por ejemplo tienes un for con un tiempo de ejecucion pesado sigue el flujo de ejecucion?

Comment: lo que pasa es que en ves del timeout pongo una consulta a la bd y ya cambia todo el orden de funcionamiento

Comment: se que es asincrono la ejecucion, por ese motivo uso promesas para volverlo sincrono

Comment: @rn3w entiendo que ofreciste la recompensa despues recibida de esta respuesta, pero asi como esta la pregunta, es la respuesta correcta... ahora viendo los comentarios y que no estas satisfecho, te recomiendo ampliar la pregunta y explicar el escenario que tienes en mente a fin de poder ayudarte mejor. Salu2

Comment: @MarcosGallardo modifique un poco mi pregunta

Comment: @MarcosGallardo sigue sin respetar el then que tarda `var promise = 
    // Este then SI esta encadenado
    .then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'cinco'
      setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("dos");
  },2000);
      return 'dos';
    })
    // Este then NO esta encadenado al then anterior
    .then(function (res) {
      // res es igual a 'dos'
      console.log("tres");
      return 'tres';
    });`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50139/discussion-between-marcos-gallardo-and-rn3w).

Comment: @hubman, listo. Creo que borre todos. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

El "problema" radica en la asincronía de nodeJS: aunque en ciertos escenarios es una gran ventaja, en este te perjudica ya que buscas una ejecución secuencial de las funciones.

Mediante el uso de promesas puedes conseguirlo si las vas encadenando una detrás de otra, pero están pensadas para justo lo contrario: se lanzan promesas para no bloquear el hilo de ejecución.

Answer (score 2):

No se exactamente qué es lo que necesitas hacer pero puedes obtener el orden de ejecución que quieras simplemente encadenando las promesas con la función `then`:

```
function doSomethingAsync() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var counter = 0;
    resolve(counter);
  });
}

doSomethingAsync()
  .then(function(counter) {
    console.log(++counter);      // 1
    return counter;
  })
  .then(function(counter) {
    console.log(++counter);      // 2
    return counter;
  })
  .then(function(counter) {
    console.log(++counter);      // 3
    return counter;
  })
  .
  .
  .
```

Lo que retornes dentro de la función `then` anterior será recibido como argumento de la proxima función `then` que se encuentre encadenada.

Comment: Esta bien el paso de argumento.pero Si no quiero pasar como argumento en algunos casos?

Comment: cambiando algo en tu codigo ya varia el orden `function doSomethingAsync() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var counter = 0;
    resolve(counter);
  });
}

doSomethingAsync()
  .then(function(counter) {
          // 1
    setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("1");
    },2);
    return counter;
  })
  .then(function(counter) {
    console.log("2");      // 2
    return counter;
  })
  .then(function(counter) {
    console.log("3");      // 3
    return counter;
  })`